# Why these divs are not adjacent though margin and padding are zero?

Tags: html, css

Complete working example is [here on CodePen.io](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGmNdo). There are four divs with class named `.inner-cols`
Following are styles applied to `.inner-cols`

```
.inner-cols{
  background-color:green;
  display:inline-block;
  width:200px;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}
```

As margin and padding for 4 divs has been set to 0 still why are not they are adjacent? Can anyone explain?enter code here

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
#container {
  background-color: red;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}
.inner-cols {
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#one-more-container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <!--container-->
  <div id="one-more-container">
    <div class="inner-cols">col1</div>
    <div class="inner-cols">col2</div>
    <div class="inner-cols">col3</div>
    <div class="inner-cols">col4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because inline elements are sensitive to white space. An easy fix is to simply remove the white space between your elements. Other solutions are to float the elements, or set the font size on the parent container to zero.

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
#container {
  background-color: red;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}
.inner-cols {
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#one-more-container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <!--container-->
  <div id="one-more-container">
    <div class="inner-cols">col1</div><div class="inner-cols">col2</div><div class="inner-cols">col3</div><div class="inner-cols">col4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Floating**:

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
#container {
  background-color: red;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow:auto;
}
.inner-cols {
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  float:left;
}
#one-more-container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <!--container-->
  <div id="one-more-container">
    <div class="inner-cols">col1</div>
    <div class="inner-cols">col2</div>
    <div class="inner-cols">col3</div>
    <div class="inner-cols">col4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Font size zero:**

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
#container {
  background-color: red;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  font-size:0;
}
.inner-cols {
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size:16px;
}
#one-more-container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <!--container-->
  <div id="one-more-container">
    <div class="inner-cols">col1</div>
    <div class="inner-cols">col2</div>
    <div class="inner-cols">col3</div>
    <div class="inner-cols">col4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting spaces between divs because each div has been given inline-block. Read the below link to remove spaces between inline-elements https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/.